# Laravel: How to create a download response for an external file?

Tags: php, laravel, download, laravel-5

I know there have already been [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531692/laravel-file-download) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437969/laravel-file-downloads) [downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44051722/laravel-file-download-php-fileinfo-extension-not-enabled) [files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194154/laravel-file-download-response-content-type-is-text-html-in-localhost) with Laravel, but all I found deal with **local** files.

So, normally, I would do something like this:

```
$path = storage_path().'/my-file.pdf';
$name = 'new-name.pdf';
$headers = '....';

return response()->download($path, $name, $headers);
```

But **what do I do, when the file I need to download is external**, laying under *www.my-storage.net/files/123/my-file.pdf* ?

I could use the [copy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) function, or a combination of [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and Laravel's [Storage::put()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/filesystem#storing-files), but **I don't want to store the file locally** (and temporarily) every time a download is being processed. Instead, I want to download the external file directly via user's browser.

In plain PHP, it would be something like **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php)**. But...

(1) How do I prepare such Laravel download response?

(2) How do I make sure the Laravel solution stays efficient (so, e.g. no memory leaks)?

Answer (score 10):

Something like the following would work:

```
 return response()->stream(function () {
      //Can add logic to chunk the file here if you want but the point is to stream data
      readfile("remote file");
 },200, [ "Content-Type" => "application/pdf", 
          "Content-Length" => "optionally add this if you know it", 
           "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=\"filename.pdf\"" 
]);
```

This works by using Symphony's [StreamedResponse](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/StreamedResponse.html)

Comment: Some of the files are of the size of 100MB. Any known concerns about using the `stream()` method with larger files? Should I maybe chunk the file anyway?

Comment: @lesssugar This particular solution uses `readfile` which does not pre-load the file but rather streams it, however take a look at the note at [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) where it says: *readfile() will not present any memory issues, even when sending large files, on its own. If you encounter an out of memory error ensure that output buffering is off with ob_get_level().*

Comment: Are you sure the callback is correct? Currently, the browser outputs file contents instead of downloading the file. I'm passing the file URL in place of the `'remote file'` value. I also tried setting `"Content-Type: application/octet-stream"`

Comment: My bad, I had another output before the response got returned, which broke the call. Thanks.