# How to Access the Storage File

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, filesystems

How to Access the Files in Storage.

**File Location**

```
storage/uploads/documentUpload/3_1620028799.PNG
```

**Remember** : `php artisan storage link` will not works because files are not in app/public folder.

File URL http://example.com/storage/uploads/logo/logo.png  404 error.
is any way to overwrite in htaccess?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If it's not under `public` it is not accessible publically. It would be a security issue if it were. You can however do something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44131415/487813) and stream the file in Laravel code. this would also allow you to put the route behind middleware if you want to require authorisation for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new disk in your `config/filesystems.php`, for example uploads

```
'uploads' => [
    'driver'     => 'local',
    'root'       => storage_path('app/uploads'),
    'url'        => env('APP_URL') . '/storage/uploads',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

and at the end of `config/filesystems.php` file, add a new symlink for uploads folder

```
'links' => [
    public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    public_path('storage/uploads')  => storage_path('app/uploads'), // Add this
],
```

Then run `php artisan storage:link`

Whenever you want to get the url of file, just run

```
\Storage::disk('uploads')->url('documentUpload/3_1620028799.PNG');
```